# SysDebugStr() Equivalent in Xcode Debugging?

Tags: xcode, debugging, trap

Back in the day on the Mac in debuggers we were able to call a function:

```
SysDebug();
```

or

```
SysDebugStr( aString );
```

which would in the first case stop in the debugger as if a manually set break point was encountered. It was basically a break point set and executed by code.

The second would both break in the debugger and display the string (good for watching values).

Printing to the console is primitive but workable.  I could define the aforementioned functions and then in the function insert a break point manually... but does anyone know if a system trap for engaging the debugger exists in Xcode / macOS / iOS / iPadOS?